# How to specify the execution order of filter and query in an Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following query in Elasticsearch:

```
GET nyc_visionzero/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                   "fuzzy": {
                      "on_street_name": "AVENUE"
                   }
               }
            ], 
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                   "borough": "MANHATTAN"
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Is the `filter` part executed first and then `fuzzy` or its the other way around? What if I want to change the order of their execution! How can I do that?

Comment: Why particular order matters to you? Is it about performance?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order that post may help.

Comment: @DarthKotik The results could be different.

Answer (score -2):

This question relates to the query vs. filter context topic. Everything in the query context (here `query.bool.must`) counts to the score of a document whereas the conditions in the filter context (`query.filter`) are a yes/no decision.

So from a performance perspective, filters are faster and can be cached. On the other side queries allow for some fuzziness.

There is a much more detailed explanation on this in [the elasticsearch docs on query and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).

Comment: This does not answer the question at all